# How calc() function works in CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to use `calc()` for my css. I have created a simple Fiddle where I have two divs. One has a class with a style using `calc()`. But it's not having any effect. Div's height is not changing.

```css
.cont {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="cont" style="background-color:blue">fsdfds</div>
<div style="background-color:red">1234</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UF3mb/696/)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is percentage height not working on my div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728022/why-is-percentage-height-not-working-on-my-div)

Comment: Add `html, body { height: 100%; }` to your CSS. See the link in Michael_B's answer for more information. Be aware that adding this CSS may affect other elements which use % height.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `calc()` function is working fine.

It's *percentage heights* you need to better understand.

In order for a percentage height to work on an element, there must be a defined height on the parent (unless the child is absolutely positioned).

Here's a post with a detailed explanation:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Here's your fiddle demo with pixel heights instead: http://jsfiddle.net/UF3mb/697/